# How can I send multiple e-mails with C# smtp client?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I just started with c# and want to write a code for school project a mailer basically I want to send e-mails to all the emails saved in a txt file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

with this code  I can send only to a single e-mail address I want a function to send e-mails to all the email address I've saved it in a txt file one by one with multi thread. HOW CAN I DO THIS ??

Comment: you basically ask the community to do the whole task for you

Comment: I believe your second parameter, can be a list of emails separated by a semicolon, so build a string with each email address in it separated by semicolon. And there is an `async` version of the send method [smtpclient-sendasync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-mail-smtpclient-sendasync(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-object))

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Using comment from Ryan Wilson

Very easy to do using the following:

```
List<string> toAddresses = new List<string>(); // get from file using any chosen way

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
    EnableSsl = true
};

foreach (var item in toAddresses)
{
    tasks.Add(client.SendMailAsync("myusername@gmail.com", item, "subject", "body"));
    Console.WriteLine($"Email sent to {item}");
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Or you can make use of [Parallel.ForEach](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/11438/parallel-foreach-loop) from [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

Comment: Good point, didnt look to far into it so will adjust

Comment: Looks like a viable solution. +1

Comment: Adjusted it to not have the old edit in and instead only show viable solution

Comment: File.ReadLines(fileName) can i use this for the file to read the e mail addresses

Comment: @Aman `File.ReadAllLines(fileName)` can be used. This [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-C-Sharp/) gives more information how you can approach reading a file

Comment: I am really sorry to disturb the all masters i just want know how can i add a txt file path  to the above code so that i can send e mails to all the users or addresses present in txt file if anyone can help me then please otherwise i need to do all in python i just want to do something new in my school

Comment: `//Default file. MAKE SURE TO CHANGE THIS LOCATION AND FILE PATH TO YOUR FILE   
  static readonly string textFile = @ "C:\Temp\Data\Authors.txt"; `